# What is the default __iter__ function?

Tags: python, iterator

I wrote a class which have `init`, `__getitem__` and `__len__` functions.
After making the `__getitem__` function more complex I noticed an iteration over the object doesn't know when to stop (although `__len__` working as intended).

So what is the default `__iter__` doing then?

my code for example (although it shouldnt matter a lot):

```py
class SubsetDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, source_dataset: Dataset, desired_classes: list):
        self.source_dataset = source_dataset
        self.desired_classes = desired_classes
        self.index_to_sub = dict()
        i = 0
        for j, d in enumerate(self.source_dataset):
          sampel, label = d
          if label in self.desired_classes:
            self.index_to_sub[i] = j
            i += 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sample, label = self.source_dataset[self.index_to_sub[index]]
        return sample, label     

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.index_to_sub)
```

my `__iter__` and `__next__` function that solved the problem (which I didn't want to implement):

```py
    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n >= len(self):
          raise StopIteration
        next = self.source_dataset[self.index_to_sub[self.n]]
        self.n += 1
        return next
```

Comment: It will call `__getitem__` with an increasing index until `__getitem__` raises an exception.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem!